# Coordinate transformation of sf sfc object does not seem to be working

Tags: r, r-sf

I have a R sf object:

```
library(sf)
library(magritr)

g1 = structure(list(ele = c(1819.80249, 1821.150879, 1825.393188, 
1817.905029), time = structure(c(1542700973, 1542701079, 1542701326, 
1542701500), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    geometry = structure(list(structure(c(36.228614, -0.38239
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(36.228447, 
    -0.382341), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(36.227496, 
    -0.382352), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(36.227352, 
    -0.382332), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(36.227352, -0.38239, 
    36.228614, -0.382332), .Names = c("xmin", "ymin", "xmax", 
    "ymax"), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
        proj4string = NA_character_), .Names = c("epsg", "proj4string"
    ), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), .Names = c("ele", "time", 
"geometry"), row.names = 2:5, class = c("sf", "data.table", "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), .Names = c("ele", "time"), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
"identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Which shows as

```
> g1
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 36.22735 ymin: -0.38239 xmax: 36.22861 ymax: -0.382332
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
       ele                time                   geometry
2 1819.802 2018-11-20 08:02:53  POINT (36.22861 -0.38239)
3 1821.151 2018-11-20 08:04:39 POINT (36.22845 -0.382341)
4 1825.393 2018-11-20 08:08:46  POINT (36.2275 -0.382352)
5 1817.905 2018-11-20 08:11:40 POINT (36.22735 -0.382332)
```

I would like to transform the coordinates to CRS=32736:

```
g1 %>% st_set_crs(32736) %>% st_transform(crs=32736)
```

which gives:

```
Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 36.22735 ymin: -0.38239 xmax: 36.22861 ymax: -0.382332
epsg (SRID):    32736
proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
       ele                time                   geometry
2 1819.802 2018-11-20 08:02:53  POINT (36.22861 -0.38239)
3 1821.151 2018-11-20 08:04:39 POINT (36.22845 -0.382341)
4 1825.393 2018-11-20 08:08:46  POINT (36.2275 -0.382352)
5 1817.905 2018-11-20 08:11:40 POINT (36.22735 -0.382332)
```

The coordinates have not been reprojected. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you first say the coordinates are 32736: `st_set_crs(32736)`, and the you transform to the same coordinates; `st_transform(crs=32736)`.... so (of course) nothing changes.... You have to use `st_set_crs` to set the coordinate-system of the original shapefile... and then use `st_transform`  to transform to 32736

Comment: thanks - the original crs is NA. I cannot go straight into the transformation, because st_transform(g1, crs = 32736) gives "Error in st_transform.sfc(st_geometry(x), crs, ...) : 
  sfc object should have crs set"

Comment: you have to find a way to figure out the coordinate-system of your input data...

Comment: It's lonlat WGS84 crs 4326.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

based on the comments above:

```
g1 %>% st_set_crs(4326) %>% st_transform(crs=32736)
```

is probably what you are looking for

```
# Simple feature collection with 4 features and 2 fields
# geometry type:  POINT
# dimension:      XY
# bbox:           xmin: 859306.9 ymin: 9957667 xmax: 859447.5 ymax: 9957673
# epsg (SRID):    32736
# proj4string:    +proj=utm +zone=36 +south +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
# ele                time                 geometry
# 2 1819.802 2018-11-20 08:02:53 POINT (859447.5 9957667)
# 3 1821.151 2018-11-20 08:04:39 POINT (859428.9 9957672)
# 4 1825.393 2018-11-20 08:08:46 POINT (859322.9 9957671)
# 5 1817.905 2018-11-20 08:11:40 POINT (859306.9 9957673)
```