# Cannot transform sfc object with missing crs, but st_crs shows object does have crs

Tags: r, r-sf

I am trying to plot some longitude/latitude coordinates using a coordinate system.

```
# Reprex
# Data I received was prepared this way 
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
test_df <- 
  data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:6],
             lon = c(-71.2280234, -112.0863874, -80.2432839, -83.9638426, -76.9199742, -77.097455),
             lat = c(42.4286907, 33.5080943, 26.6374761, 43.4304646, 40.2398118, 39.0023604)) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('lon','lat')) %>% 
  rename(geo_col = geometry) %>% 
  as_tibble()
```

## Plotting without CRS

Oddly, I'm able to plot it fine if I don't set a CRS.

```
new_df <- 
  test_df %>%
  mutate(geometry = geo_col) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf() 

ggplot(new_df) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  theme_void()
```

## Plotting with CRS

But if I try to set a CRS, ggplot2 seems to suggest the CRS is missing even though it is clearly present.

```
# Plotting after setting CRS
new_df <- 
  test_df %>%
  mutate(geometry = geo_col) %>% 
  sf::st_as_sf() %>% 
  sf::st_set_crs(value = 4326) 

ggplot(new_df) + 
  geom_sf() + 
  theme_void()
Error in st_transform.sfc(X[[i]], ...) : 
  cannot transform sfc object with missing crs
```

But it does have a CRS...

```
> st_crs(new_df)
Coordinate Reference System:
  User input: EPSG:4326 
  wkt:
GEOGCRS["WGS 84",
    ENSEMBLE["World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble",
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)"],
        MEMBER["World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)"],
        ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
        ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    CS[ellipsoidal,2],
        AXIS["geodetic latitude (Lat)",north,
            ORDER[1],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
        AXIS["geodetic longitude (Lon)",east,
            ORDER[2],
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]],
    USAGE[
        SCOPE["Horizontal component of 3D system."],
        AREA["World."],
        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],
    ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

Previous answers seem to suggest you have to set the crs before any transformations are done.

[Coordinate transformation of sf sfc object does not seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692695/coordinate-transformation-of-sf-sfc-object-does-not-seem-to-be-working)

But it makes no difference if I try using `st_transform()` after using `st_set_crs()`.

I'm wondering if maybe there's something about me creating a column called geometry and then running `st_as_sf()` on it?

Comment: I can't reproduce the error of sf>tibble>sf>set_crs and then not being able to plot. What versions of tibble, sf, and ggplot2 are you using?

Comment: Running the code exactly as I wrote it? That's odd. `sf_1.0-12` and `ggplot2_3.4.0` and `tibble_3.1.8` with R version 4.2.1.

Comment: Hmm, I'm 1-2 minor versions behind you on each package, but I doubt this is a newly introduced bug. Odd behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as seems to be the case, I have misread the question - and the problem is not in getting the data into R properly, but repairing data that was for whatever reason broken on import, but we are stuck with it because that is how the world works:

Consider also the following code; what it does is that it takes the (bad, bad!) `test_df` tibble and converts it back to proper `{sf}` object.

It again uses `sf::st_as_sf`, but this time points to geo_col as the column containing geometry, and sets crs to 4326 on import.

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
# misformed tibble to be repaired
test_df <- 
  data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:6],
             lon = c(-71.2280234, -112.0863874, -80.2432839, -83.9638426, -76.9199742, -77.097455),
             lat = c(42.4286907, 33.5080943, 26.6374761, 43.4304646, 40.2398118, 39.0023604)) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('lon','lat')) %>% 
  rename(geo_col = geometry) %>% 
  as_tibble() # this strips the magical juice! bad, very bad...

# new dataframe rises from ashes of the old!
new_df <- test_df %>% 
  st_as_sf(sf_column_name = "geo_col", crs = 4326)

# a visual check
mapview::mapview(new_df)
```

[image]

Edit: it seems that the issue with your new_df was the use of a mutate call to construct new geometry column. As a consequence your data frame has two geometry columns: one called `geometry` and the original `geo_col`. Only one of which is active at a time, and gets resolved from "unknown" to "known" CRS (note the little degree sign in header, showing the units).

```r
new_df
# Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
# Active geometry column: geo_col
# Geometry type: POINT
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -112.0864 ymin: 26.63748 xmax: -71.22802 ymax: 43.43046
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
# A tibble: 6 × 3
#   id                 geo_col             geometry
# * <chr>          <POINT [°]>              <POINT>
# 1 A     (-71.22802 42.42869) (-71.22802 42.42869)
# 2 B     (-112.0864 33.50809) (-112.0864 33.50809)
# 3 C     (-80.24328 26.63748) (-80.24328 26.63748)
# 4 D     (-83.96384 43.43046) (-83.96384 43.43046)
# 5 E     (-76.91997 40.23981) (-76.91997 40.23981)
# 6 F     (-77.09745 39.00236) (-77.09745 39.00236)
```

Having two geometry columns in different CRSes is technically possible, but generally unadvisable as all sorts of funny stuff can happen...

IMHO this might be considered as a bug on part of ggplot2, which really should have known better - even though it is being asked to plot a sf object, and there is a column callled `geometry` present it is not the active geometry column as per {sf} specs, and it should be  ignored for plotting; see:

```r
attr(new_df, "sf_column")
# [1] "geo_col"
```

But this is kind of an error that is easier to sidestep than resolve I am afraid...

Comment: Very nice! This is actually a better solution for my scenario so I'll change the accepted to this one.

Comment: I thought so - after I having read your comment on my first answer, and dwelt on it a bit :) I'm glad it worked for you

Answer (score 2):

When you use the `sf::st_as_sf()` call with a vector of coordinates you need to tell your R session how to interpret the figures. Do they mean degrees on sphere, or meters on a plane? Or are you an American, feeling patriotic and using US Survey Feet?

I strongly suspect that lat & lon are degrees on a sphere, and should be interpreted within prism of WGS84, but you need to tell your R session that.

As an example consider this piece of code, noting my slightly adjusted call of  `sf::st_as_sf()`:

```r
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

test_df <- data.frame(id = LETTERS[1:6],
                      lon = c(-71.2280234, -112.0863874, -80.2432839, -83.9638426, -76.9199742, -77.097455),
                      lat = c(42.4286907, 33.5080943, 26.6374761, 43.4304646, 40.2398118, 39.0023604)) %>%
  sf::st_as_sf(coords = c('lon','lat'), 
               # this part is important!
               crs = 4326) %>% 
  rename(geo_col = geometry)
  
# to double check a visual overview; looks legit...
mapview::mapview(test_df)
```

[image: a map with points labelled A to F]

Comment: Interesting, so there's no way to recover if the original data didn't have `crs=4326` when the original `sf::st_as_sf()` was called?